# Why bluetooth Hands free devices don't need an app to work with Android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to create my own hands free bluetooth device and I am being reading about bluetooth these days, now I have a Motorola hands free device and I noticed that it doesn't need an app installed on the cellphone in order to work, it just needs to be paired with the cellphone and that's all, in android Developer web page they show you how to use bluetooth to discover, connect and pass information between the cellphone and a bluetooth device, but you need to create an app and have it opened to work, so I have the next doubt, how the commercial hands free do to work without needing an app? Or they need an app but it's hidden and is installed the first time a connection is stablished? or is there an Android API that let's you do this? I hope you could help me or tell me where I could find more information about this, thanks you in advance

Comment: "how the commercial hands free do to work without needing an app?" -- AFAIK, it is a feature of the operating system. Operating systems, like Windows, OS X, Linux, Android, iOS, etc., all have built-in capabilities that may or may not be implemented by what you would think of as an "app". You do not need an app to offer Bluetooth hands-free access any more than you need an app to support a headphone jack.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of achieving this? Because all the information I have found, even in android developers, needs an app in order to work. Now, I first though that they could do that because they are big companies like motorola that have some agreement with the cellphone companies or with Google. But I have seen some key chains that can take pictures without needing apps, just synchronize with the device and that's all, I don't think that you need to have a permission in order to do this.